# Output knobs from Altium 3DS as "filmstrip" image array

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, 3ds-max

I'm a project manager coordinating development of audio plugin software. Our GUI designer is using Altium 3DS to build a 3D photo-realistic GUI, and will then output images from there for the software to use for knobs, etc.

The plugin software wants the knobs to be provided as image arrays -- where a knob is embodied by a single PNG file which is a horizontal, end-to-end concatenation of all the images that are shown as a knob turns through its rotation.

My 3D designer tells me that 3DS can render the knob out as single frames, and he has to then manually assemble all these together in a single "filmstrip" image array. I want to lid that time consuming and error prone assembly process, perhaps by using a capability of 3DS, or a Photoshop Action, or so image assembly utility? **Can anyone suggest the most effective method?**

Comment: Do a search for pngstitch thats what ive been using for stitching 3ds max exports. Also doing synth gui.

Comment: most effective is not defined. Certainly all suggested methods can be made automatically launched after render so need no human input.

Comment: I wish you'd choose an answer so this question would quick being bumped to the top.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and its command line interface. The program ships with at least Maya so might be present on your system if you have the full Autodesk 3d suite (maya calls it imconvert). If you just install ImageMagick standalone then you would just call the following from command line or batch (you can also call this as a post render hook if yous wish):

```
convert inputfile01.fmt ...  inputfileNN.fmt -gravity West -append outfile.fmt
```

You may want to use gravity South, East, North instead also.

Answer (score 0):

The question here is, you need to collate a selection of similar images into a single strip image?

There are ways in Photoshop that you could do this with actions, but I've also come across a tool recently called [Shoebox](http://renderhjs.net/shoebox/), it's mainly for sprite editing, but you should be able to use its film strip feature to create your image.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ImageMagick there is [Fiji](http://fiji.sc) app that have GUI.

Here's tutorial: http://fiji.sc/Stitch_and_Align_a_sequence_of_grid_images_Tutorial